# Element in HTML form is undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that I have a HTML form with 4 text inputs, I submit it to a javascript function and the first 3 inputs work just fine but the fourth is undefined.

Here is the important code:
The HTML part:

```
<form action="insertServer.php" method="post" id="insertServer">
Navn:       <input type="text" name="navn" id="navn">
Netid:      <input type="text" name="netid" id="netid">
Serverid:   <input type="text" name="serverid" id="serverid">
Location:   <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="button" id="submitButton" value="Indsend">
</form>
<div class="resultInsert"></div>
```

The Javascript part:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> //Add server
$("#insertServer").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$("div.resultInsert").html("Location is:"+location.value+" navn is: "+navn.value);

});
</script>
```

When I type data into the fields and press submit the first 3 values are just fine but the fourth is shown as "undefined"

In case you need to see the entire file, I have created a gist for it here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8052481

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never try to access an element through the DOM by using its `id` as if it was a global variable.

Some browsers make this possible (as a very ugly legacy of Internet Explorer 4's), but it isn't reliable.

In this case, `location` is [the standard location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) and not your HTML element.

Get the element through the DOM using `getElementById`, jQuery's selector engine or something similar.

```
var location = jQuery('#location').val();
var navn = jQuery('#navn').val();

$("div.resultInsert").text("Location is:" + location + " navn is: " + navn);
```

Also note that I've used the `text` method instead of the `html` method. Someone might type something with special meaning in HTML into the inputs. Don't let that break the output.

Answer (score 2):

`location` (address object) is predefined variable and cannot be used in other way.

```
$("#insertServer").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$("div.resultInsert").html("Location is:"+$('#location').val()+" navn is: "+$('#navn').val());

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but I would select Quentin's answer because it is more informative and have a better solution for me.